# Contains in Android

Tags: android, string, contains

here is my code :

```
public String text="",buffertext="", finaltext="", oldText="";

....

case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED: { //8192
                text = new String(event.getText().toString());
                Log.e(text,oldText);
                if (text.contains(oldText)){
                    oldText=new String(text);
                }else{
                    buffertext += oldText+"\n";
                    oldText="";
                }
                break;
            }
```

In debug I have oldText = AA and text = AAA, but the contains return false :( !!

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I copy a test, there is the code:

```
 case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED: { //8192
                text = event.getText().toString();
                Log.e(text,oldText);
                if (text.contains(oldText)){
                    oldText=text;
                }else{
                    buffertext += oldText+"\n";
                    oldText="";
                }
                break;
            }
```